# Не изменяются данные в shelve

Tags: python

```
>>> db = shelve.open('shelvefilebd.txt')
>>> db[1] = 1, 2500
>>> db['1']

(1, 2500)

>>> db['1'][0] = 2
```

Я хочу изменить 1 на 2, но выходит следующая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    db['1'][0] = 2
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Python | Shelve

Comment: Текст ошибки означает, что данный тип данных не поддерживает измения. Нельзя изменить то, что неизменяется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная ошибка тесно связана с понятиями immutable и mutable объекты в python.

Список "неизменяемых" (immutable) сущностей:

- int
- float
- decimal
- complex
- bool
- string
- tuple
- range
- frozenset
- bytes

Список "изменяемых" (mutable) сущностей:

- list
- dict
- set
- bytearray
- классы создаваемые пользователем

Кортежи (tuples) не "изменяемы" поэтому операции присвоения значений его элементам не осуществляются. Чтобы поменять значения переведите в "изменяемый" тип, например список `list(db)`.

```
t_tuple = (1,2)
t_tuple[0] = 10
# TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

t_list = list(t_tuple)
t_list[0] = 10
print t_list
# [10, 2]
```

Comment: Мне не очень понятно, можно в коде пожалуйста, я начал изучать python меньше двух недель назад.

Comment: добавил пример.

Comment: `>>> import shelve
>>> t_tuple = shelve.open('test.txt')
>>> t_tuple = (1,2)
>>> list(t_tuple)
[1, 2]
>>> t_tuple[0] = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    t_tuple[0] = 10
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> t_list = list(t_tuple)[0]
>>> t_list[0] = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    t_list[0] = 10
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
>>> `

Comment: там потрите `[0]` я опечатался, а вы успели скопировать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить на

```
 db[1] = [1, 2500]
```

Comment: Можно было добавить что `1, 2500` это тоже самое что `(1, 2500)`, т.е. литерал создания кортежей (tuple), а они неизменяемые в отличии от списков

Comment: `>>> db[1] = [1, 2500]
       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    db[1] = [1, 2500]
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shelve.py", line 125, in __setitem__
    self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)] = f.getvalue()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
>>> db['1'] = [1, 2500]
       
>>> db['1']
       
[1, 2500]`